# Monte Carlo DataFrame is Highly Fragmented

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and trying to run a monte carlo sim for a class.  I'm receiving the below error:

PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
results.loc[i, 'Power1']=Power1

I tried the below code:

```
for i in range(10000):
    Power1=np.random.normal(16000,1000,1)
    Power2=np.random.triangular(12000,15000,18000)
    Efficiency1=np.random.normal(.88,.10,1)
    Efficiency2=np.random.normal(.85,.05,1)
    TotalPower=(Power1*Efficiency1)+(Power2*Efficiency2)
    results.loc[i, 'Power1']=Power1
    results.loc[i, 'Efficiency1']=Efficiency1
    results.loc[i, 'Power2']=Power2
    results.loc[i, 'Efficiency2']=Efficiency2
    results.loc[i, 'TotalPower']=TotalPower
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over each row, you might want to try the following.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10000

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['power1', 'efficiency1', 'power2', 'efficiency2', 'totalpower'])
result['power1'] = np.random.normal(16000, 1000, N)
result['power2'] = np.random.triangular(12000, 15000, 18000, size=N)
result['efficiency1'] = np.random.normal(0.88, 0.10, N)
result['efficiency2'] = np.random.normal(0.85, 0.05, N)

result['totalpower'] = result['power1']*result['efficiency1'] + result['power2']*result['efficiency2']
```

Comment: Effective and very efficient answer!